# Deployment error: This org does not have the appropriate permissions to use the 'ContentHubGDrive' data provider

Tags: deployment, files-connect

After configuring and setting up `Files Connect for Google Drive` in my dev environment, when deploying to staging environment, I get this error:

```
This org does not have the appropriate permissions to use the
'ContentHubGDrive' data provider
```

Deployment package included:

- Auth Provider for Google Drive
- External Data Source `GoogleDrive`
- Custom Object `items_GoogleDrive__x`
- Permission Set granting

  - Read access to the custom object
  - Enabling `Files Connect Cloud`
  - External Data Source Access to `GoogleDrive`

Why does this error happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the permission `ContentHubGDrive` is actually the permission `Files Connect Cloud` (hat tip to @DanielBallinger [Mappings Between Salesforce Permissions](http://www.fishofprey.com/2020/10/mappings-between-salesforce-permission.html))

The target org of the deployment does have `Files Connect` enabled

However, the running user of the deployment does not *yet* have `Files Connect Cloud` permission as that permission is embedded with the permission set being deployed and hence obviously hasn't yet been assigned to the running user in the target org (*Catch 22*).

The error message is misleading as it is not an org permission but is really a running user permission that is missing.

**Action:**

1. Create a Permission Set called `Files Connect`, enable `Files Connect Cloud` within the permission set
2. Deploy that permission set to the target org
3. Assign the running user that does deployments to the `Files Connect` permission set.
4. Deploy the External data source and its associated custom object plus whatever else is part of your deployment package (auth provider, custom tab, etc)

*Notes*

Presumably, a similar error occurs for the other Files Connect data source types such as:

- `Files Connect: Box`
- `Files Connect: Microsoft Sharepoint`
- `Files Connect: Microsoft OneDrive`

Comment: you, my friend, are today's hero! Thanks for saving me tons of time!